# Convert Bash String to JavaString

Tags: java, string, bash, sh, implicit-conversion

I want to convert a String present in the bash variable to Java Supported String style.

For Example:
`data="{"5": ">10%", "4": "<5%", "3": ">28 months", "2": "20%", "1": 100}"`

as 
`echo $data`

Giving me this result:

```
    "{\n" + 
    "    \"1\": 21,\n" + 
    "    \"2\": \"40%\",\n" + 
    "    \"3\": \"<24 months\",\n" + 
    "    \"4\": \"<5%\",\n" + 
    "    \"5\": \">10%\"\n" + 
    "}"
```

But also I need to transfer this value into a file using `echo "String data = $data;" >> file.txt` where data is value after processing where it is throwing weird result as

```
String data = "{
" + 
"   \"5\": \">10%\",
" + 
"   \"4\": \"<5%\",
" + 
"   \"3\": \">28 months\",
" + 
"   \"2\": \"20%\",
" + 
"   \"1\": 100
" + 
"}";
```

But expected was:

```
String data = "{\n" + 
        "   \"1\": 50,\n" + 
        "   \"2\": \"40%\",\n" + 
        "   \"3\": \">28 months\",\n" + 
        "   \"4\": \"<5%\",\n" + 
        "   \"5\": \">10%\"\n" + 
        "}";
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Attempt 1: echo "${data//$'\n'/"\n\" +"}

Attempt 2: echo $data | tr "\"" "\\\""

Attempt 3: echo "${data//\""\\"}"

Attempt 4: sed -E 's/"/\\&/4g; s/\\"(,)?$/"\1/

With no success

Comment: Please include what you tried **in the question**, properly formatted. Comments are not appropriate for code. Use them only to inform that you made changes. All important information about the question should be in the question itself.

Comment: In some IDEs one can copy text and paste it between `"|"` and the text is expanded as desired. Or you store the text in a _resource_ file on the class path, packed in the application jar.

Comment: @vfalcao, the solution is failing in one condition when json value has more quotes in form of array like:
`"array": ["val1", "val2"]` then the output is like:

```" \"array\": [\"val1\",\n" +
                "\"val2\"],\n" +``` so is there a fix for this??

Comment: @KNDheeraj, the solution is not actually _failing_, it just that you have a new requirement.... in any case, I have updated the solution, adding  a negative lookahead to the regular expression.

Comment: @vfalcao After doing some proper research, I found out that the issue is in `jq` bash json parser which is breaking each element of array into it's separate line. Your solution is working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a greatly `adhoc` approach:
(invoking perl **twice**)

```
data='{"5": ">10%", "4": "<5%", "3": ">28 months", "2": "20%", "1": 100}'
echo $data |\
perl -pe 's/{/{\n/; s/}/\n}/; s/, /,\n/g; s/^"/   "/gm' |\
perl -0pe 's/"/\\"/g; s/\n/\\n" + \n/g; s/^/"/gm; s/\}\\n.*$/}"/'
```

The result is:

```
 "{\n" +
 "   \"5\": \">10%\",\n" +
 "   \"4\": \"<5%\",\n" +
 "   \"3\": \">28 months\",\n" +
 "   \"2\": \"20%\",\n" +
 "   \"1\": 100\n" +
 "}"
```

Further testing:

```
test='{"first" : "1st", "second": "2nd", "third" : "3rd" }'

echo $test |\
 perl -pe 's/{/{\n/; s/}/\n}/; s/, /,\n/g; s/^"/   "/gm' |\
 perl -0pe 's/"/\\"/g; s/\n/\\n" + \n/g; s/^/"/gm; s/\}\\n.*$/}"/'
```

returns

```
"{\n" +
"   \"first\" : \"1st\",\n" +
"   \"second\": \"2nd\",\n" +
"   \"third\" : \"3rd\" \n" +
"}"
```

As for outputting this new string, try:

```
data='{"5": ">10%", "4": "<5%", "3": ">28 months", "2": "20%", "1": 100}'
newdata=$(echo $data |\
perl -pe 's/{/{\n/; s/}/\n}/; s/, /,\n/g; s/^"/   "/gm' |\
perl -0pe 's/"/\\"/g; s/\n/\\n" + \n/g; s/^/"/gm; s/\}\\n.*$/}"/')

echo "String data = $newdata" >> /tmp/file.txt
```

As for the update (*using `sh` instead of `bash`, and getting 2 `\t`s *), try the following
(it's getting uglier and uglier...') :

```
data='{"5": ">10%", "4": "<5%", "3": ">28 months", "2": "20%", "1": 100}'
newdata=$(echo $data |\
perl -pe 's/{/{\n/; s/}/\n}/; s/, /,\n/g; ' |\
perl -0pe 's/"/\\"/g; s/\n/\\n" + \n/g; s/^/"/gm; s/^"/\t\t"/gm; s/^\t\t"/"/; s/\}\\n.*$/}"/')

/bin/echo "String data = $newdata" >> /tmp/file.txt
```

As for getting the arrays in the same line, as requested by @KNDeeraj, we can use:

```
data='{"array": ["v1", "v2"], "5": ">10%", "4": "<5%", "3": ">28 months", "2": "20%", "1": 100}'
newdata=$(echo $data |\
perl -pe 's/{/{\n/; s/}/\n}/; s/, (?!.*?\])/,\n/g; s/^"/   "/gm' |\
perl -0pe 's/"/\\"/g; s/\n/\\n" + \n/g; s/^/"/gm; s/\}\\n.*$/}"/')

echo "String data = $newdata" >> /tmp/file.txt
```

The result is:

```
"{\n" +
"   \"array\": [\"v1\", \"v2\"],\n" +
"   \"5\": \">10%\",\n" +
"   \"4\": \"<5%\",\n" +
"   \"3\": \">28 months\",\n" +
"   \"2\": \"20%\",\n" +
"   \"1\": 100\n" +
"}"
```

Comment: Leading quotes are missing

Comment: Well they are still missing

Comment: Oops, leading quotes for every line, ok. I think the command is fine now.

Comment: @vfalcao in my bash script, I have to use the `echo` command twice in my code, so can you direct me how can I escape the `\n twice` in my `perl -pe` command

Comment: @KNDheeraj, please update your question with this additional info... maybe showing those two **echo**s you just cited.

Comment: Updated the answer as well.

Comment: @vfalcao, I had 2 updates for your code snippets -> 1) Your code is working when shell file starts with **#!/bin/bash** but gives unexpected result when it starts with **#!/bin/sh** 2) Still there is a problem with indentation like in the question, I asked if there is a way that after 1st line each line should have 2 \t space gap for better code representation. Is it doable?

Comment: @KNDheeraj, doing things in `sh` usually is different than doing things in `bash`, and your question was tagged `bash`. In any case,  I have tried with `sh`, and I will update the answer.

Comment: @vfalcao Thanks for the solution, it is perfect!!